# declare function signatures in flow

Tags: javascript, facebook, flowtype

Flow documentation has a way of declaring modules and classes, but I don't see anything outside the source code for declaring methods on classes. This is especially useful if you want to be implementing something like an abstract base class. Can it be done? What I want is this:

```
class A { 
 declare function myfun(t : T) : S; 
}
```

where `S` and `T` are types already declared elsewhere (I don't want to introduce type variables just yet). We can use the workaround:

```
class A {
  myfun(t : T) : ?S { return null; }
}
```

Even if I set the subclasses to emit non-null return values, I still get flow warnings about null checks.

Answer (score 0):

An interim solution that typechecks is:

```
class A { 
  myfun: (t : T) => S;
}
```